# CSS - Internet Explorer makes image sizes slightly bigger

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am working with Internet Explorer (8) and it seems that the images grow slightly bigger. Actually it seems the whole template grows slightly bigger on Internet Explorer and makes the background images bigger and thus... blurry. In Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safariit's all good!

Here's an image to illustrate my horrible dilemma. 
[image: oh... IE.]

This happens EVEN with a simple image on the page and a full XHTML template.

Comment: How's this image embedded? Code please!

Comment: This is not reddit, your rage faces have no place here. And are you sure you're viewing your pages zoomed at 100% and not something higher?

Comment: Heh.  Are you viewing your web page at 100%, or with a zoom?

Comment: I added pastebin links! @Dan - THAT'S FREAKY. We both have the same name and reputation. What are the odds! @Cory: What's reddit? I got those images off ot tumblr. How do i check for not 100% on IE? Nevermind.. I'm stupid.. it was indeed the zoom-function on IE. All is well!

Comment: You can press Ctrl-0 to reset the zoom to 100%. (Ctrl +/- to zoom in/out). i think its a shortcut in all the browsers

Comment: @Cory - I believe the actual source of this rage meme is 4chan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to move this here.  Maybe it will get your attention:

```
Heh. Are you viewing your web page at 100%, or with a zoom?
```

The explanation of your problem suggests that your browser is 'zoomed in', and displaying everything at, say 110%.

Although this may not be noticeable for natural-style images like photos, it will certainly degrade 8-bit sprites of this nature.